# Why is Send port null

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, dart-isolates

I want to update the UI when I receive background notification from Firebase.

I have a backgroundMessage handler
`

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> handleBackgroundNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) async {
  try {  
    final SendPort send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('port_firebase');
    send.send(remoteMessage.notification.body);
    
  } catch (e) {
    log(e.toString());
    throw e;
  }
}
```

`And I am registering my Receive port and background handler inside`initState`.

```
bool res = IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
          _port.sendPort, 'port_firebase');
      log('status $res');
      if (res) {
        log('port created successfuly');
        _port.listen((dynamic data) {
          log('port  ' + data.toString());
        }, onError: (e) {
          log('error is ${e.toString()}');
        });
      }
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundNotification);
```

It registers the port successfully but whenever I receive background notification. It gives me error

```
 NoSuchMethodError: The method 'send' was called on null.
      Receiver: null
      Tried calling: send("Welocme to FCM")
```

Does anyone have solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add await in this line

```
final SendPort send = await IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('port_firebase');
```

Comment: I am getting this
" 'await' applied to 'SendPort', which is not a 'Future'"